# When should os.File.Close() be called explicitly?

Tags: go

I seems that whether `f.Close()` is commented out or not in the following program, the result is the same. Does anybody know when `f.Close()` should be explicitly called?

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "log"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    f, err := os.OpenFile(os.Args[1], os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE, 0666)
    if err != nil { log.Fatal(err) }
    defer f.Close()

    off, err := strconv.ParseInt(os.Args[3], 0, 64)
    if err != nil { log.Fatal(err) }

    _, err = f.WriteAt([]byte(os.Args[2]), off)
    if err != nil { log.Fatal(err) }
}
```

```
$ go run main.go output.txt abc 10
$ xxd < output.txt
00000000: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 6162 63         ..........abc
```

Comment: Not closing a file can lead to leaked memory and filehandles.

Comment: @Flimzy can you provide the command to check the filehandle and showing that the filehandle is not released upon the termination of this go program. My understanding is that the filehandle will be automatically released whether Close() is explicitly called or not.

Comment: `lsof` is what you're looking for.

Comment: @user11980328: What is your "understanding" based upon?

Comment: If a program got `kill -9`, the filehandle should not be occupied anymore. Therefore, when a program is terminated normally, even the filehandle is not released explicitly, it should not require explicit release either.

Comment: Yes, terminating a program closes all open files. So in that sense, if you know your program will exit right away, you can skip the explicit close. But if your program runs for a long time, then not closing files will lead to memory and file handle leaks.

Answer (score 3):

You should call `File.Close()` when the `File` object is no longer needed.

The actual implementation is OS specific, but will close the file descriptor, prevent any further I/O, and free the resources for garbage collection (at the Go level), or reuse (at the kernel level).

One pathological consequence of not calling `Close` on a long running program with many open files would be running out of open file descriptors, blocking all I/O for that user (or even the entire system).

In general, skipping `File.Close()` means you cannot be guaranteed that the write succeeded. In all OSes writes are not committed to disk upon return of the `Write(...)` call but are buffered. Calling `File.Sync()` or `File.Close()` tends to be the only way to surface errors encountered when flushing all buffers. This is the same reason `defer f.Close()` should not be used when you actually care about catching errors.

In your particular code sample, you're not checking the error returned by `f.WriteAt` so any problem will be ignored. In this very specific scenario, calling `f.Close` really doesn't matter as you already have no guarantee that the file was written successfully.

Comment: My question is specific to this example code, whether it is needed to close the file explicitly. Not in general whether file should be closed explicitly or not. If for this specific code, Close() must be explicitly called. Could you find a situtation when Close() is not explictly called, then some error will occur? If not such condition can be found, then Close() is not needed.

Comment: @user11980328 Taking a hex dump of the file written by the program and judging the behaviour of `*os.File`'s method `Close` by that is not correct. Do understand the reason on why actually `Close` is used from this answer itself. There's nothing special in your code for which it needs to specifically answered.

Comment: Added a section about skipping (or ignoring errors from) `File.Close()`. In short: don't do it.

Comment: And another addition about your specific code sample since this doesn't seem to be about good file handling practices.

Comment: I have added the error checking for `f.WriteAt()`. Do you have a reproducible example showing that if f.Close() is skipped, then the output won't be correct?